# How to loop YouTube videos?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, youtube, userscripts

Is there any plugin/script for Google Chrome (or any other browser) which allows me to play any YouTube video in a loop without any user intervention? I know of youtuberepeater.com but I don't want to visit another site just to loop the video.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Youtube Enhancer script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/33042) adds controls that include a loop button.

[image]

As can be seen in the picture you can not only loop the entire video, but easily loop an arbitrary section using the Begin and End buttons.

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quick kludge for firefox (prolly something similar for chrome) reloadevery plugin

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/

just reload the page at video length + a few seconds to buffer it.

Should work as youtube videos auto start.

Comment: Didn't try this but wouldn't reloading the page lead to bandwidth loss particularly if you are watching a long running video or if the internet speed comes at a premium?

Comment: Yes, but i'm assuming that for most people that likely isn't an issue. My personal option would be to just download the video to my machine, but i assumed that was too much hassle given youtuberepeater being ruled out.

Comment: actually, it may just reload it from the cache in your temporary internet files directory. Give it a go, if it loads the entire video in a few seconds upon reload, it's not grabbing it from the net twice. I actually suspect it wont download it twice now i think about it.

Comment: upon a little testing, for me it's loading it from cache the second time and so only downloading it once.

Comment: Found one for Google Chrome. Testing it now. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ofojbjgaaddibdfpmmjeonahgbacejid

Comment: Update: It works in Google Chrome and reloads the page successfully. But the video also gets reloaded. So the bandwidth issue still remains. Haven't tested it in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

A Chrome extension available at: http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mcdpnidfhfjfbafmpppcplcejgepadbo

You can loop a single YouTube video using EZ Looper @ http://www.ezlooper.com
By far the easiest looper around…

Answer (score 1):

You can use Enhancer for Youtube extension available for chrome and firefox.

[Chrome Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhancer-for-youtube/ponfpcnoihfmfllpaingbgckeeldkhle?hl=es) [Firefox Link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enhancer-for-youtube/)

If you are on Android or iPhone then create playlist and then click on auto replay icon in the playlist. There are also many websites such as youtubelooper.net which can do the job for you.

Source: https://digitblogger.com/how-to-loop-youtube-videos/

Answer (score -2):

Using [youtubeloop.net](http://youtubeloop.net) is the easiest way to loop a YouTube video.

Comment: He said that he didn't want another website.